# frequency seperate column in python

Tags: python, frequency

I probably have a simple question, but I can't find the answer on this platform. I have a set of columns in my dataset df, like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

When I want the frequency of column A I have the following script:

```
df.A.value_counts()
```

And I get:

A    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

But now I want the counts of all the 4 columns. I've made the following script:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].value_counts()
```

I want to get the output: A 3, B 2, C 1, D 3. But I only get the count of A, and not the other columns. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are missing a ```]```

Comment: ow sorry, I have that in my script, but it still doesn't work. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the number of ones if I interpret your output correctly. You can use the `sum()` function for this:

```
print(df.sum())
```

Gives me following output with your input:

```
A    3
B    2
C    1
D    3
dtype: int64
```

The function [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) gives you the unique values in a column, which would give you `1` as output for any column. So, I assumed it is not what you want.

**EDIT:**
If you want only a few columns you can filter the columns first and then apply the sum. Example:

```
# Select the columns; example without C
columns_you_want = ['A', 'B', 'D']

# Filter df before applying the sum function
print(df[columns_you_want].sum())
```

Output are only the wanted columns (no C):

```
A    3
B    2
D    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I've simplified my dataset. In reality it's more complex. I just want the output of 4 specific columns, but my real dataset is much larger. How can I correct my script?

Comment: Ok I understand but is the number of ones what you want? or is it the number of unique values? I added an example where you can select the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count specific values that are in few different columns you can use:

```
df[df == VALUE].count()
```

In this example this is:

```
df[df == 1].count()
```